# Spring Security - Double auth: X.509 for terminal, login form for user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, x509certificate

I'm glad that you are here reading my question :)

I'm developing a web app in spring-boot for a sales shop. I made a login system that uses formLogin() for the users authetication (it works like a charm), but I came across a problem when refers to detect in which computer is logged the user. As another facts, only certain computers should be able to access to the site and only one user at time. Also, I have both (user and terminal) implemented in the database linked with Spring-data JPA, and the terminal has a foreign key to the user (null when no one is connected to it).

After 3 days googling I concludded that the best way to implement this is install X.509 certificates in each computer to do mutual authentication and use a loginForm for users privileges. (The terminals doesn't have permissions but configuration like "this should work with that cash register" or "this should use that receipt printer").

So, the code-part...
This is my actual Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/static/**", "/login", "/catalogo/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and()
            .csrf()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }
}
```

And this is my UserDetailService:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    // This is my user model service in Spring-data JPA, I have one too for terminals
    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserService securityUserService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        SecurityUser user = securityUserService.findByUsername(username);
        logger.info("User : {}", user);
        if(user==null){
            logger.info("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true,
                true, getGrantedAuthorities(getPermissions(user)));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> permisos) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permiso : permisos) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permiso));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    private List<String> getPermissions(SecurityUser user) {
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<SecurityPermission> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SecurityRole role : user.getRoles()) {
            collection.addAll(role.getPermissions());
        }

        collection.addAll(user.getPermissions());

        for (SecurityPermission item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }
}
```

Basically now I have to add the X.509 certificate authentication. I made it without the login form and works well, but I don't know how to handle both together.

Thanks for your help.

PS: if you think that you have another possible solution for this problem, don't be afraid to post it

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to use the client certificate authentication to get the details of the connected user, then you only need to stablish a secure TLS channel with two ways authentication. You do not need to modify your spring application

Configure a TLS channel that requires client to present a certificate. The browser will prompt user to select one from keystore. The server will verify it and if it is acceptable will stablish the secure channel.

The configuration is specific for each server, so look for the documentation of yours.

You will need to install the client certificates in each computer, and if you are using a selfsigned certificate, install also the public part in the trust store to avoid browser warnings

It would be possible to use the X509Certificate at client side to identify users and avoid the login form. It requires to issue a certificate for each user and install it in te computer/s that the user is going to use. If conputers are shared then certifucates should be protected with a password. probably is not a good alternative to you